# Is it possible for matrix trace?

Tags: matrices, trace, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Suppose we have two positive semidefinite matrcies $X_1$ and $X_2$ of size $N\times N$ with elements from complex numbers. Suppose $Tr(X_1)>Tr(X_2)$ then is it possible that for any non-zero vector $s$ (of size $N\times 1$ with complex elements) we have $$Tr(ss^HX_1)=Tr(ss^HX_2)$$ where $s^H$ is the hermitian transpose of $s$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is $Tr(X_1)>Tr(X_2)$ meaningful?

Comment: @C.F.G. Why not?

Comment: @C.F.G In my problem, I know that the traces of two matrices are different.

Comment: @FrankMoses Do you want to know if it is possible that there exists a non-zero vector $s$ such that the traces are the same or that for all non-zero vectors $s$ the traces are the same?

Comment: @MaoWao excellent comment. Actually, I want to show that $Tr(ss^HX_1)= Tr(ss^HX_2)$ is not possible for any non-zero vector $s$. In other words, I want to show that there does not exist any non-zero $s$ such that $Tr(ss^HX_1)= Tr(ss^HX_2)$.

Comment: @MaoWao: Because the matrices are complex entries and trace is complex as well I think.

Comment: @C.F.G But the matrices are assumed to be positive semidefinite, so their traces are real (non-negative even).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
X_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\,X_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\,s=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $\mathrm{Tr}(X_1)=3>2=\mathrm{Tr}(X_2)$ and $\mathrm{Tr}(ss^H X_1)=1=\mathrm{Tr}(ss^H X_2)$.

Of course, one should expect an example like this: By the cyclicity of the trace, we have $\mathrm{Tr}(ss^H X_j)=s^H X_j s$. So the condition $\mathrm{Tr}(ss^H X_1)=\mathrm{Tr}(ss^H X_2)$ only controls the behavior of $X_1$ and $X_2$ on the subspace generated by $s$. This leaves us enough room to get any relation between the traces of the matrices by modifying them appropriately on the orthogonal complement of $s$.